# Simulator/device UI differs from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 to create a very simple, single view iPhone app. I've laid out the view as you can see in the IB image. (`UIViewController`, `UIView`, `UIButton`, `UITextView`).

When I run the app in the simulator (or my phone) it looks like the second screen shot.

I don't understand why the simulator UI doesn't look like the one I created in IB.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image: InterfaceBuilder]
[image: Simulator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have an iPhone 5 sized layout in Xcode and a iphone 4 in simulator. Check the constraints on the dark grey vs bottom views and make sure that they'll resize how you want.

Answer (score 10):

If you look you are using the iPhone 5 size layout in your storyboard file. To change the dimensions between iPhone 5 layout and the standard iPhone size

Click on the icon in the lower right hand corner of the storyboard:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to see the layout in a iPhone 5 simulator. In the iOS simulator go to  Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina 4-inch). This is the iPhone 5 layout. However, if you do not have a retina displayed computer. The iPhone will look like a really big iPad.

Comment: By XCode 5.1, it was moved farther left, but thanks for the reminder! I was racking my brain trying to remember where that widget was!

Answer (score 0):

Hey so here is another method.

My Problem: 
1.My Storyboard was showing a fat rectangle that didnt look anything like a iPhone. Then when I'd run the simulator all the element were cut off and not in the right position.
2.Simulator took up the whole screen.

Resolution: 
1. Make sure you Storyboard is open and displayed, click on the frame so that it has a blue highlighted border. Then on the Utilities manager (on the right) click on "Show the Attributes menu". The very first item should be Simulated Metrics. Choose the size that best fits your screen/needs.

2.Follow [Adjusting the XCode iPhone simulator scale and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size) I scaled it down to 33%

Best,
Nate