# Xcode 6.3.1 iPhone simulator looms huge on my screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, scale, simulator

I just upgraded to Yosemite and Xcode 6.3.1. Now, when I run my iPhone app in the simulator (set for iPhone 5S), it looks like this on my 24" screen:

[image]

It appeared about half this size in 6.1.1. Now, I actually have to scroll to see the whole simulator.

I've looked around on SO and Google, but am maybe using the wrong keywords. Anybody have any ideas why it has ballooned up like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS Simulator, Window > Scale and select the scaling that you want.

Alternatively you can use command 1-5 to adjust the size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently change it, see below! It worked like a charm thanks to Dren answered Jan 9 '15 at 9:01:

To obtain it follow next easy steps:

quit simulator if open
open terminal (from spotlight for example)
paste next text to terminal and press enter
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"

You can try any scales changing 0.4 to desired value.

To reset this custom scale, just apply any standard scale from simulator menu in way described above.

link to question/answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856936/7058890)

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size/27856936#27856936

Comment: Yup Dren rocks! It solved my problem instantly.

Comment: Wait you rated it down? I credited Dren for it...