# Changing iOS simulator scale on Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm using MacBook Air, and the iOS simulator for iPhone 6 Plus is just too big to fit on the 13" screen so it shows vertical scroll bar. I've tried to change the scale, but I found that it's already on 50% scale at Window > Scale... and there's no further option for 33% and smaller (e.g. there's only cmd+1 for 100%, cmd+2 for 75%, and cmd+3 for 50%). I'm fairly new at coding in Xcode and iOS. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In Xcode 7, there are now options for 25% and 33% as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Kalpesh at:
[Adjusting the XCode iPhone simulator scale and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size)

and the answer from Neo at:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62757/how-do-i-resize-the-ios-simulator

works for me.

How to do:

1. Quit simulation if open.
2. Open terminal (from spotlight for example, type terminal).
3. Paste this next text to the terminal and press enter. Change the 0.4 to any scale you wish (with 0.4 equals to 40%).
   `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"`
4. Or alternatively, go to `/Library/Preferences` and edit `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` file. Edit value for KEY `SimulatorWindowLastScale` to desired scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cmd+4 and cmd+5 too. Sadly, the MacBook Air does not have retina display.

Comment: I have tried that too. And nothing happened when I pressed cmd+4 and cmd+5. Something did happen if I pressed cmd+1 or cmd+2 (means that there are certainly no option for cmd+4 and cmd+5). Yeah, it's too bad. But I got to go with what I have. :)