# Xcode 7 - Iphone 6 Plus Simulator is huge, Is that normal?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-6-plus

I just recently upgraded from Xcode 6 to Xcode 7 and I built a test viewcontroller with a single button on it.

When I run the app, the simulator is pretty big, and contains scrollbars by default both horizontally and vertically.

Is that normal or is there a way to make it fit on the Iphone 6 plus without the scrollbars?

[image]

Comment: I believe this question and answer may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size

Answer (score 1):

Simulator.app's Window menu has an option to set the scale.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your simulator using command+1, command +2 ..till command+5 you can manage

Answer (score 0):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner or simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot.

[image]