# Xcode Simulator scale

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, scale, xcode9, simulator

I am trying to change Simulator scale to 40%. I found that it can be changed using - defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"

I modified plist file, tried adding this key with with 0.4 value, also modified SimulatorWindowLastScale-com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 to 0.4, but I cant seem to get 40% scale.

Has anyone tried this recently.

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size/18606992  Check this one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47173670/6137672 see this

Answer (score 0):

I know about existing thread, thanks anyways.

Looks like attribute has changed, this works - 
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale-com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 "0.4"

Comment: Have you tried this with the new Xcode9? Can't seem to get it to work. Thanks