# iOS simulator opens zoomed to 33% when I have an extra screen connected

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

I am working on a mac and I connect an extra screen. 
When I run react-native run-ios from my terminal, the simulator appears in my main screen (probably because that's the one focused when I run the command ), and it's zoomed out to 33%.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856936/3001617 partially solves my problem, but the size is set top 50% according to the main screen I am using.

Is there a way to open the simulator automatically in the secondary screen and set a default zoom view of the simulator according to that screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting the XCode iPhone simulator scale and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size)

Comment: thanks @MichaelCheng, that question certainly helps, but I edited my question because I have a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xcode 9-iOS 11 simulator, you can pick & drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot.

[image]