# Manage zoom level on Xcode9 simulators

Tags: ios11, xcode9

Since Xcode 9 came out the simulator scale is disturbed. Here there is not any option of scaling further to 100% on some simulators and sometimes I am unable to switch to 100 % scale at all.

After searching on net I found out that sometimes if zooming doesn't work I need to do following to get it 100% zoom.

> 1. Uncheck Window -> Show Device Bezels
> 2. Click Window -> Zoom
> 3. Check Window -> Show Device Bezels

Is it something that I am missing to scale it further if I want to or current Xcode doesn't support further scaling at all.

Comment: This question is already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size) by someone.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just drag the corner of the simulator window.[image]

Comment: amazing, I really could not even thought about it)

Comment: I mean there's no real indicator that you could do that. I mean yeah it's an os convention to be able to pull on the sides to grow a window but there's no frame to pull so it makes people not treat it like a normal OS/X app. When you think about it's kinda poorly designed in that respect :P

Comment: Yeah obvious its an option but we can't zoom it beyond screen size or if we make it zoom, we can't scroll all the way to bottom.